# How to return a subset of a list that matches a condition

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of `int`s:

```
listOfNumbers = range(100)
```

And I want to return a list of the elements that meet a certain condition, say:

```
def meetsCondition(element):
    return bool(element != 0 and element % 7 == 0)
```

What's a Pythonic way to return a sub-`list` of element in a `list` for which  `meetsCondition(element)` is `True`?

A naive approach:

```
def subList(inputList):
    outputList = []

    for element in inputList:
        if meetsCondition(element):
            outputList.append(element)

    return outputList

divisibleBySeven = subList(listOfNumbers)
```

Is there a simple way to do this, perhaps with a list comprehension or `set()` functions, and without the temporary `outputList`?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use list comprehension,

```
divisibleBySeven = [num for num in inputList if num != 0 and num % 7 == 0]
```

or you can use the `meetsCondition` also,

```
divisibleBySeven = [num for num in inputList if meetsCondition(num)]
```

you can actually write the same condition with Python's [truthy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=truth#truth-value-testing) semantics, like this

```
divisibleBySeven = [num for num in inputList if num and num % 7]
```

---

alternatively, you can use `filter` function with your `meetsCondition`, like this

```
divisibleBySeven = filter(meetsCondition, inputList)
```

### `%timeit`

```py
listOfNumbers = range(1000000)

%timeit [num for num in listOfNumbers if meetsCondition(num)]
[out]:
243 ms ± 4.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit list(filter(meetsCondition, listOfNumbers))
[out]:
211 ms ± 4.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```